# Bootstrap full width row within a container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to know if I can create a full width row within a container div using Bootstrap 3.1.1.

As you can see from this example: http://www.bootply.com/otvG4TYeNw#
The content is being centered. How can I make it full width?

Please take note that it HAS to be within the container wrapper.

Comment: if you want full width in that case you should remove  class `container` or move all the from the class `.container`. then only you can get 100% width.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to do that because the container is in the base template which i don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your container class by default has that length. Adding a `width: 100%` on the container style worked for me.

Comment: Hi David. Could you share with me a example from bootply? Thanks!

Comment: Hi David, as you can see from your example, there are still padding on the left and right. It is technically not full width yet.

Comment: How about this? http://www.bootply.com/fAAy1bzUyi
Just added a padding of 0 to both sides